# \hslash with other letter

Tags: symbols, amsmath, amssymb

I would like to know how to make a character like `\hslash`, but with a 'd' instead of an 'h'.
I know that `\hbar` is defined using `\mathchar'26`, might there be a similar character for the slash in `\hslash`?

Comment: Here: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html ? `\dj`?

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for the diagonal 'slash', not the horizontal 'bar'.

Comment: there is probably no reason that the same `\mathchar'26` can't be used, just with some horizontal adjustments to make sure it crosses the stem in the correct place.  sorry, i don't have access to a system where i can test it at the moment.

Comment: Apologies, I must be explaining myself poorly. `\mathchar'26` is a short _horizontal_ line used in the definition of `\hbar`. The character that I seek is a short _diagonal_ line, similar to the one appearing in the character `\hslash` in the `amssymb` package.

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\hslash` symbol is a unique glyph. Here's an emulation of it obtained by scaling, rotating and raising a minus sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\newcommand{\hslashslash}{%
  \raisebox{.9ex}{%
    \scalebox{.7}{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{18}{$-$}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\dslash}{%
  {%
   \vphantom{d}%
   \ooalign{\kern.05em\smash{\hslashslash}\hidewidth\cr$d$\cr}%
   \kern.05em
  }%
}
\begin{document}
$\hslash\ne\dslash^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But how did you find that angle? I am clueless. :)

Comment: @HarishKumar Trial and error; the first attempt was 20 degrees, but typesetting it over the `\hslash` revealed it was too much; with 18 degrees it was perfect. There's no indication of the angle in the Metafont source for `\hslash` (`bsymbols.mf`, character octal 175). The bar is slightly thicker for `\dslash`, though. :(

Comment: This is beautiful, just what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: If now I try to use this inside of a command like $\vec{\dslash}$, this gives interesting results... How would you solve this to avoid that the arrow is so high?

Comment: @mwoua I get [this picture (click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOEia.png)

Comment: @egreg Hmmm... Cause I get this: [link](https://imgur.com/XI6nY6J) Note that I tweeked it a bit to do it on p rather than d. Edit: without any changein your code (by keeping it on the letter d, not tweeking the numbers etc) I still get an arrow much higher than the normal \vec{d}...

Comment: @mwoua Well, You seem to have defined incorrectly `\pslash`. Please, open a new question with all details.

Comment: @egreg Well it ooks like it... But the thing is, when I copy-paste your code, I have the same thing: an arrow too high. I will open some new question.