# Special double integral symbol - unable to find it in a4symbols list

Tags: symbols, amssymb, integral

I have been using `$\fint$` and `$\iint$` for average integral and double integral respectively.

Is there a symbol which combines both, i.e `$\iint$` with a horizontal line across as in `$\fint$`? I can't find one in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive).

Edit: After the very helpful answer by Mico, I am trying to add a tilt to the horizontal dash. I do not understand the code by Mico well enough to be able to modify it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169296/124577) showing how to insert a slash into a d, you could try it with `\iint` instead of d.

Comment: Do you use any particular math font package or specialized symbols package (e.g., `esint`) for the `\fint` macro?

Comment: I usually use esint, wasysym,tikz,graphicx and mathtools.

Comment: What angle should be used in the tilt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(updated the answer to address the OP's follow-up request for a symbol with a tilted crossbar)

Here's a solution that builds on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220209/5001). The names of the user macros are `\fiint` and `\tiltfiint`, respectively. In the code shown below, the angle of tilt is set at 15 degrees. Feel free to modify this setting to suit your taste.

If you happen to use a math font symbols package other than (or in addition to) `amssymb`, the double-integral symbol (`\iint`) will likely be spaced more tightly than is the case if just `amssymb` is loaded. If that's the case, simply replace the directive `\def\longdash{-\mkern-3.5mu-}` in the code below with either `\def\longdash{-\mkern-5.5mu-}` or -- especially if the `esint` package is loaded -- `\def\longdash{-\mkern-7.5mu-}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \iint macro
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \rotatebox macro
\def\Yint#1{\mathchoice
    {\YYint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
    {\YYint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}%
      \!\iint}
\def\YYint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\iint}$}
    \vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$}}\kern-.51\wd0}}
\def\longdash{{-}\mkern-3.5mu{-}} 
   % consider using "\mkern-7.5mu" if esint package is loaded
\def\tiltlongdash{\rotatebox[origin=c]{15}{$\longdash$}}
\def\fiint{\Yint\longdash}
\def\tiltfiint{\Yint\tiltlongdash}

%\usepackage{esint} %% optional
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \fiint_u^v f$ 
\quad
$\fiint_u^v f$

\medskip
$\displaystyle \tiltfiint_u^v f$ 
\quad
$\tiltfiint_u^v f$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the absolutely fantastic answer. This works exactly as I wanted.